What is the meaning of 多岁 in 在中国，60多岁已经是退休的年纪了?
在中国，60多岁已经是退休的年纪了, ...
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 21.
What is the meaning of 多岁? Maybe it is 年代, like "s" in English? 60多岁 = in 60s? If so, what is the difference between 多岁 and 年代?
在中国，60年代已经是退休的年纪了, ...
Is it completely the same?

60岁 = 60 years old
多 = more than --> over --> plus some
60多岁 = over 60 years old = 60-some years old
Similarly:
60人 = 60 people
60多人 = over 60 people -> 60-some people
It has nothing to do with 年代 (era)
60年代 = the 60s era
Similarly:
20年代 = the (19)20s (most would say 上世紀20年代 = the 20s in the last century)
2020年代 = the 2020s era (some might say 本世紀20年代 = the 20s in this century)
Since it is only 2024, you don't have to mention 'the last century' when referring to the 30s era and later

在中国，60多岁已经是退休的年纪了


In China, sixty-some years old is already a retirement age

Isn't it true for most countries? Canada's official retirement age is 65. Some countries may be younger, I presume 70 years old retirement age is quite rare

六十多岁 means the age is 61 to 65. It can include 60. If being 66 to 69, you can say 快70岁了。

年代 is "era" - in the era of 1960, which is often shorthand for "in the 60s" = 在1960年代.
60多岁 = 6X years old, X is a number 1 thru 9; 61, 62....69, any number greater than (多於) 60 but less than 70.
